# Query nested entity collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Does anybody can help me, I can't find out how to only select the not deleted card from a nested entity.

```
  var userCardSetList1 = _cardSetRepository.GetMany(
                x => x.Include(c => c.Card).ThenInclude(ca => ca.CardAnswer),
                x => x.UserId == UserId &&
                     x.IsDeleted == false &&
                     x.Card.Any(c => c.IsDeleted == false));
```

Thanks

Comment: Where instead of Any?

Comment: Nope, then I get the error Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'IEnumerable<Card>'

Comment: I usually create a helper method that does the recursion and call the method from linq.

Comment: @user1861065 let me confirm, in selected `CardSet` there can be both deleted and not deleted cards (which is listed in `Card` property) and you want only not deleted cards ? right?

Comment: Rather than `== false`, use `!x.IsDeleted`.

Comment: @ Amit, yes in the CardSet List are at the moments card which are flagged as IsDeleted = true and IsDeleted = false. And I would like to have in the cardset only the cards which are IsDeleted = false.